# Angular directive not working with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi I am trying to run Jquery Flex slider. 
Flex slider work without ng-repeat like here : http://plnkr.co/edit/aVC9fnRhMkKw3xfpm4No?p=preview

But not working with using ng-repeat like this:

http://plnkr.co/edit/nW3i9bmUwtlbXn2Vhy4O?p=preview

directive :

```
.directive('flexslider', function () {

return {
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

  element.flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
  });
}
}
});
```

working themplate:

```
<div class="flexslider" flexslider>
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/200">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/200">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/200">
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/200">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Not working themplate:

```
<div class="flexslider" flexslider>
  <ul class="slides">
    <li ng-repeat="n in list">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/200">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

list in mainCtrl:

```
 $scope.liste = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

Comment: Could you include your controller code? Where you define `list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the directive was fired before the repeat process

this fixes the issue:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    element.flexslider({
      animation: "slide"
    });  
  },500);
```

working here http://plnkr.co/edit/rZN49pPm7lQdYnECGiM9?p=preview

Comment: You probably want to use blue his solution. This is much safer, since this doesn't rely on a timeout.

Answer (score 4):

This is due to lazy load of img.

You can use following

```
 <div ng-view>
    {{myFoo()}}
  </div>
```

and in myFoo function just invoke the flexSlider

```
$scope.myFoo = function(){
    $(".flexslider").flexslider({
        animation: "slide"
      });
  }
```

Here's [Fiddler](http://plnkr.co/edit/npAPsK9xt8vSJwZFnbhX?p=preview)

Or you can follow this link
[Lazy Load Flex](https://web-design-weekly.com/snippets/lazy-loading-images-flexslider/)